# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout$1

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here is my stack-trace.

> Exception Details java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   android/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout$1   at
>   android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:91)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)   at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.BridgeActionBar.(BridgeActionBar.java:84)
>   at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.AppCompatActionBar.(AppCompatActionBar.java:56)
>   Copy stack to clipboard !

[please look the error on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTH7B.png)

Comment: What are you trying to implement exactly? Include enough details for the issue!

Comment: Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorListener Copy stack to clipboard

Comment: show us some code, tell us where and with which SDK version you are compiling, and which version runs on the device where you run the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes Android Studio has some rendering problems, so you could do three things in this situation:

**Firstly:** be sure to have imported right `appcompat-v7 library` in your project structure (in your dependencies)

**Secondly:** change the `AppTheme` in the preview window to NOT an `AppCompat` theme. You could try with some Holo themes, for example Holo.light or Holo.dark.

**Thirdly:** You could change the Android Version when rendering layouts - for example, you could get it back to API level 21

Comment: thank you very much for answering how to check "Firstly: be sure to have imported right appcompat-v7 library in your project structure (in your dependencies)" :/

Comment: Go in your libs folder and see there if the appcompat-v7 library is there

Comment: so, if you have it, try with second and third - try to change the AppTheme or the Api Level for the preview rendering

Comment: thank you very very much it was the  Secondly, i change theme and its ok!! thank you very much. can i ass you, did you know why show me "no debbugable application" :)

Comment: You're welcome :) To remove the "no debuggable application" message, you also should have Tools->Android->Enable ADB Integration active.

Comment: oh my god!!!! :)  thank you really thank you!!! :) you safe me!!!! :) i wish you have a nice day!!! :) <3 XX

Comment: I'm glad to help you :) Have a nice day you too :))